# Using multiple function in external JavaScript sheet

Tags: javascript, html, function

in my "website" I have a series of riddles that have answers that are revealed once you click on them. in an external javascript sheet I have ten individual functions that are listed as such:

```
function myQuestion1() {document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = "When it's turned into the teacher";}
```

I am trying to figure out how to work a multiple function. I already have a question for a test on this feature. In HTML I have it written like so:

```
<p onClick="revealAnswer('answer11','When it is turned into the teacher')">When is homework not homework?</p>
```

in my external JavaScript sheet, I have it written as such:

```
function revealAnswer(answerId, answer){document.getElementById("answerId").innerHTML = "answer";}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: jsfiddle link please

Comment: Remove the quotes around `answerID` and `answer" :)

Comment: Just a tip use jQuery. It is not that hard to learn and will make your life 100,000 times easier. Try the Codecademy course.

Comment: @ChristianJuth I believe learning pure javascript is better as you get a better understanding of what's going on with the source code. jQuery is easy to use because it's just a cheat sheet for javascript. Don't get me wrong, it's a great time saver but for learning I think it's better to learn how to create your own functionality rather than calling a pre-coded function from the jQuery library.

Comment: @NewToJS I either agree with your or very much disagree. If you are saying jQuery should not be used because it is a cheat sheet then that is simply crazy. If you are simply saying the best way to develop your skills is to learn javascript then jQuery I agree.

Comment: @ChristianJuth I'm not saying it shouldn't be used. I clearly pointed out it's a great time saver. I'm saying for the purpose of learning it's better to learn pure javascript.

Comment: @NewToJS Yes I agree it is better to start off with pure javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont quote your variables, else they're interpreted as strings:

```
var x = "Hello there!";
console.log(x); //"Hello there!"
console.log("x"); //"x"
```

So, for your code:

```
function revealAnswer(answerId, answer) {
    document.getElementById(answerId).innerHTML = answer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had a short instruction on this in class, my instructor didn't have a lot of time to feed us all of the details and explain it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function revealAnswer(answerId, answer){
document.getElementById(answerId).innerHTML = answer;
}
```

Comment: How did this get an upvote when the current post is incorrect. A simple typo but still voted up. You're missing function revealAnswer(answerId, answer`)`{}

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the quotation mark error mentioned by others, you could also simplify the work by hiding the elements with CSS instead. That might be a bit advanced if you're learning JS, but it will make your html much lighter.

CSS

```
.answer { visibility: hidden; };
```

HTML

```
<p onclick="revealAnswer(event)">
    Why was 6 affraid of 7?
    <span class="answer">
        Because 7 ate 9!
    </span>
</p>
```

JS

```
function revealAnswer(e) {
    e.target.querySelector(".answer").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eqt36xtz/

Comment: I appreciate the CSS idea Jacque. I specifically requested JS because it was being taught to us as an early lesson in my HTML and Javascript class. My professor only taught us this 5 minutes before class ended and really wasn't able to tell us much.